# Vulnerable link from Skype contact

Tags: malware, attacks, exploit

Last time I have got suspicious link from some of my Skype contacts. The link looks like:

> h**ps://www.google.com/url?sa=t&url=%68%74%74%70%3A%2F%2F%63%32%36%34%2E%72%75&usg=AFQjCNFczxOu-pqCubz7HJppKMWrNYbi5Q&id=[my-skype-account]

I have changed protocol part to `*` and remove my Skype account from link.

How does it works? And what do I need to do if I click on this link in my iPhone? I suspect that opening this link will infect me, but not sure that iOS is the target platform.

*Update:*

As I see this URL

- redirect to `option4life3.com` site
- use `ip-api.com` to get current location using my current IP
- working with `history` API of the browser - I don't understand what it does exactly (here is a script: `h**p://option4life3.com/media/bbo.js`

Answer (score 3):

Could be anything from referral stuff to password steal. %68%74%74%70%3A%2F%2F%63%32%36%34%2E%72%75" translate from hex as http://c264.ru .

From there, anything can run further (scripts, etc).

Answer (score 0):

I've found some interesting things:

- Anchor tag with href: h**p://option4life3.com/unsub.aspx
- More files: h**ps://urlscan.io/result/fef5934c-2b1e-4a82-8236-a9c0cbfc3e55#transactions

Nothing seems to be an exploit, it seems to be an AD url.

Comment: What is an `AD URL` ? Advertisement ?

Comment: I meant: an URL that redirects/shows an Advertisement, but it seems to be offline or not working

Comment: The capitalization of the D made me think active directory for a split second